# Is there a way to return args to command line in Python (Compiled to EXE) to a JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, command-line, exe

So, I am making a node program and there are many things which Python can do and JavaScript can't like using modules Python-specific, etc. So, I decided to compile the Python files to EXE and then use invoke them using JavaScript with the code below...

```
const execFile = require("child_process").execFile;
function openExe(filePath, args = "") {
  execFile(filePath, [args], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error("stderr", stderr);
      throw error;
    }
  });
}
```

Then I wrote this in Python...

```
import sys 
from pyowm.owm import OWM

args = (sys.argv)
args.pop(0)
print(args)


def print_weather(thing, location):
    location = location.lower()
    location = location.replace(" ", "")
    location = location.replace("weather", "")
    owm = OWM(api-key)
    mgr = owm.weather_manager()
    listOfAll = []
    listOfNotAll = []
    weather = mgr.weather_at_place(location).weather
    temp = int((weather.to_dict()['temperature'])['temp'])
    temp = round((temp - (273.15)) * 9/5 + 32)
    weather1 = str(weather.to_dict()[thing])
    listOfAll.append(f"The weather in {location} is {weather1}")
    listOfAll.append(f"The current temperature is {temp}°F")
    if temp <= 68:
        listOfAll.append("You should probably wear warm cloths ")
        listOfNotAll.append("\U0001F455")
    elif temp > 99:
        listOfAll.append("Drink some water its pretty hot...")
        listOfNotAll.append("\U0001F4A6")
    #{{{{Some way to return both (listOfNotAll and listOfAll) the lists}}}}


print_weather("detailed_status", "chennai")
```

Now what I need is some way to return the output of this file (Has been compiled to EXE) to the JavaScript file.
If that is not possible in this case then what is it that I have to change...

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print `listOfAll` and `listOfNotAll` at the end of the `print_weather` function.
For example:

```
print("listOfAll:")
for item in listOfAll:
    print(item)

print("listOfNotAll:")
for item in listOfNotAll:
    print(item)
```

The output from your python code will be captured by the stdout variable in javascript.
At this point you can do whatever you want with stdout (for example, convert it to an array of lines using `stdout.split("\n")` )

I found a blog post that's also a possible solution to your question:
https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2015/08/21/python-nodejs-comm/

Comment: Thanks a lot... I was searching for this for about 12 h